# Multiple different results returned on case-sensitive 'exact' query in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, case-sensitive

I have an instance of django 1.2.1 running on ubuntu with a mysql 5 backend. I am trying to make a case-sensitive query that should only return one result, but I am getting two results back that have the same content but with different cases.

I want to get an entry with the following title:
    Cat on the Internet syndrome

So I use the following query:

```
c = Change.objects.filter(change_type='new',title__exact='Cat on the Internet syndrome')
```

and I get the following results:

```
>>> c
[<Change: Change object>, <Change: Change object>]
```

The titles of each Change object:

```
>>> for i in c:
...     print i.title
... 
Cat on the Internet Syndrome
Cat on the Internet syndrome
```

As you can see, the 'S' in syndrome within each object's title has a different case for the S in syndrome. I was under the impression from reading the documentation [0] that all queries default to the 'exact' type. I get the same results when I do not specify `title__exact='Cat on the Internet syndrome'`.

How do I ensure that case-sensitivity is used within the query that I outline above?

[0] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-exact

Edit: 
Mysql version is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
```

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2170

> To get the functionally correctly,
>   change the Collation of the MySql?
>   database to latin1_swedish_cs or
>   utf8_bin for case sensitive
>   comparisons.

Comment: That was it. I changed the character set to utf8_bin and now I only get one result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to a setting at the MySQL level.  [From the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-collation):

> By default, with a UTF-8 database, MySQL will use the utf8_general_ci_swedish collation. This results in all string equality comparisons being done in a case-insensitive manner. That is, "Fred" and "freD" are considered equal at the database level. If you have a unique constraint on a field, it would be illegal to try to insert both "aa" and "AA" into the same column, since they compare as equal (and, hence, non-unique) with the default collation.
>
> In many cases, this default will not be a problem. However, if you really want case-sensitive comparisons on a particular column or table, you would change the column or table to use the utf8_bin collation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a note on the reference you gave regarding comparison in MySQL:

> **MySQL comparisons**
>
> In MySQL, a database table's "collation" setting determines whether exact comparisons are case-sensitive. This is a database setting, not a Django setting. It's possible to configure your MySQL tables to use case-sensitive comparisons, but some trade-offs are involved. For more information about this, see the [collation section](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-collation) in the databases documentation.